# how to replace torch.Tensor to a value in python

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, lookup-tables

my predictions in a pytorch are coming as `torch([0]) , torch([1])....,torch([25])` for respective 26 alphabets i.e. `A,B,C....Z`.
my prediction are coming as torch([0]) which i want as A and so on .
Any idea how to do this conversion .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert indices of the alphabet to the actual letters, you can:

```py
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'  # the Alphabet
pred = torch.randint(0, 26, (30,))  # your prediction, int tensor with values in range[0, 25]
# convert to characters
pred_string = ''.join(alphabet[c_] for c_ in pred)
```

the output would be something like:

> ```
> 'KEFOTIJBNTAPWHSBXUIQKTTJNSCNDF'
> ```

This will also work for `pred` with a single element, in which case the conversion can done more compactly:

```py
alphabet[pred.item()]
```

Comment: Hi , https://imgur.com/a/Oz2Y94d in image you can see that my prediction output is tensor([0]) which i want to convert as A , and so on how to achieve this like in the image value of pred is tensor([4]) which should be E

Comment: @k_p have you tried my solution? it will work for `pred` with a single element as in your case as well as with longer `pred` tensors.

Comment: ya i have tried but but not able to convert my pred tensors to desired alphabets

Answer (score 1):

You want [`Tensor.item()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html)

```py
>>> import torch
>>> t = torch.tensor([0])
>>> t.item()
0
```

If you want to convert it to a letter from `A` to `Z` you can use:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_uppercase[t.item()]
'A'
```

Be careful to check the shape before doing this, or wrap in a try/except for a possible `ValueError`:

```py
>>> t = torch.tensor([0, 1])
>>> t.item()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-6-dc80242434c0>", line 1, in <module>
    t.item()
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: I think the question was not how to get `0` from `torch([0])` tensor, but rather how to convert it to `A`